# UITraitCollection - swift to objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitraitcollection

I'm trying to convert swift to objective-C. Here is my code below:

**Swift**

```
import UIKit

protocol TraitCollectionOverridable {
    func preferredTraitCollection() -> UITraitCollection?
}

class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func overrideTraitCollectionForChildViewController(childViewController: UIViewController) -> UITraitCollection? {
        guard let conformingViewController = childViewController as? TraitCollectionOverridable else {
            return super.overrideTraitCollectionForChildViewController(childViewController)
        }

        return conformingViewController.preferredTraitCollection()
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**
header file

```
@protocol TraitCollectionOverridable <NSObject>
- (UITraitCollection *) preferredTraitCollection;
@end

@interface CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <TraitCollectionOverridable> traitsDelegate;
@end
```

.m file

```
@implementation CustomNavigationController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.traitsDelegate preferredTraitCollection];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (UITraitCollection *)overrideTraitCollectionForChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController
{
    if (CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) < CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds)) {
        return [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact];
    } else {
        return [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular];
    }
}

@end
```

My guess is overrideTraitCollectionForChildViewController is not converted properly. Any help on that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *My guess is overrideTraitCollectionForChildViewController is not converted properly.*

The **Obj-C** & **Swift** versions of `overrideTraitCollectionForChildViewController` aren't equivalent. Here is the corrected code:

## Obj-C

```
- (UITraitCollection *)overrideTraitCollectionForChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController
{
    if( [childViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(TraitCollectionOverridable)] ) {
        return [(NSObject<TraitCollectionOverridable>*)childViewController preferredTraitCollection];
    } else {
        return [super overrideTraitCollectionForChildViewController:childViewController];
    }
}
```

## Swift

```
override func overrideTraitCollectionForChildViewController(childViewController: UIViewController) -> UITraitCollection? {
    guard let conformingViewController = childViewController as? TraitCollectionOverridable else {
        return super.overrideTraitCollectionForChildViewController(childViewController)
    }

    return conformingViewController.preferredTraitCollection()
}
```